# SurfaceView not drawing bitmaps anymore in Android 4.1+

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In order to display a view with moving objects (from bitmaps) and touch events, I've been using the following code for a `SurfaceView` in Android. It has alwas worked fine on my development devices, but it turned out that lots of users just see a black box in place of that `View`. After quite a long time of (unsuccessful) debugging, I've come to the conclusion that it must be Android 4.1 which causes the `SurfaceView` to stop working correctly.

My development devices are Android 4.0 but users complaining about the black-only `SurfaceView` have Android 4.1. Checked that with a Android 4.1 emulator - and it's not working there, either.

Can you see what is wrong with the code? Is it caused by the "Project Butter" things in Android 4.1, perhaps?

Of course, I've checked that the `Bitmap` objects are valid (saved them to SD card in appropriate lines) and all methods for drawing are periodically called as well - everything's normal there.

```
package com.my.package.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.my.package.Card;
import com.my.package.MyApp;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private MyRenderThread mRenderThread;
    private volatile List<Card> mGameObjects;
    private volatile int mGameObjectsCount;
    private int mScreenWidth;
    private int mScreenHeight;
    private int mGameObjectWidth;
    private int mGameObjectHeight;
    private int mHighlightedObject = -1;
    private Paint mGraphicsPaint;
    private Paint mShadowPaint;
    private Rect mDrawingRect;
    private int mTouchEventAction;
    private Bitmap bitmapToDraw;
    private int mOnDrawX1;
    private BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions;
    // ...

    public MySurface(Context activityContext, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
        super(activityContext, attributeSet);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        setFocusable(true); // touch events should be processed by this class
        mGameObjects = new ArrayList<Card>();
        mGraphicsPaint = new Paint();
        mGraphicsPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mGraphicsPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        mShadowPaint = new Paint();
        mShadowPaint.setARGB(160, 20, 20, 20);
        mShadowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmapOptions.inInputShareable = true;
        bitmapOptions.inPurgeable = true;
        mDrawingRect = new Rect();
    }


    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
        mScreenWidth = getWidth();
        mScreenHeight = getHeight();
        mGameObjectHeight = mScreenHeight;
        mGameObjectWidth = mGameObjectHeight*99/150;
        mCurrentSpacing = mGameObjectWidth;
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mRenderThread = new MyRenderThread(getHolder(), this);
        mRenderThread.setRunning(true);
        mRenderThread.start();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        boolean retry = true;
        mRenderThread.setRunning(false); // stop thread
        while (retry) { // wait for thread to close
            try {
                mRenderThread.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) { }
        }
    }

    public void stopThread() {
        if (mRenderThread != null) {
            mRenderThread.setRunning(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (canvas != null) {
            synchronized (mGameObjects) {
                mGameObjectsCount = mGameObjects.size();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                if (mGameObjectsCount > 0) {
                    mCurrentSpacing = Math.min(mScreenWidth/mGameObjectsCount, mGameObjectWidth);
                    for (int c = 0; c < mGameObjectsCount; c++) {
                        if (c != mHighlightedObject) {
                            try {
                                drawGameObject(canvas, mGameObjects.get(c).getDrawableID(), false, c*mCurrentSpacing, c*mCurrentSpacing+mGameObjectWidth);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e) { }
                        }
                    }
                    if (mHighlightedObject > -1) {
                        mOnDrawX1 = Math.min(mHighlightedObject*mCurrentSpacing, mScreenWidth-mGameObjectWidth);
                        try {
                            drawGameObject(canvas, mGameObjects.get(mHighlightedObject).getDrawableID(), true, mOnDrawX1, mOnDrawX1+mGameObjectWidth);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawGameObject(Canvas canvas, int resourceID, boolean highlighted, int xLeft, int xRight) {
        if (canvas != null && resourceID != 0) {
            try {
                if (highlighted) {
                    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, mScreenWidth, mScreenHeight, mShadowPaint);
                }
                bitmapToDraw = MyApp.gameObjectCacheGet(resourceID);
                if (bitmapToDraw == null) {
                    bitmapToDraw = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceID, bitmapOptions);
                    MyApp.gameObjectCachePut(resourceID, bitmapToDraw);
                }
                mDrawingRect.set(xLeft, 0, xRight, mGameObjectHeight);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapToDraw, null, mDrawingRect, mGraphicsPaint);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (mRenderThread.getSurfaceHolder()) { // synchronized so that there are no concurrent accesses
            mTouchEventAction = event.getAction();
            if (mTouchEventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || mTouchEventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (event.getY() >= 0 && event.getY() < mScreenHeight) {
                    mTouchEventObject = (int) event.getX()/mCurrentSpacing;
                    if (mTouchEventObject > -1 && mTouchEventObject < mGameObjectsCount) {
                        mHighlightedObject = mTouchEventObject;
                    }
                    else {
                        mHighlightedObject = -1;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    mHighlightedObject = -1;
                }
            }
            else if (mTouchEventAction == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if (mActivityCallback != null && mHighlightedObject > -1 && mHighlightedObject < mGameObjectsCount) {
                    try {
                        mActivityCallback.placeObject(mGameObjects.get(mHighlightedObject));
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { }
                }
                mHighlightedObject = -1;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // ...

}
```

And this is the code for the thread that periodically calls the `SurfaceView`'s `onDraw()`:

```
package com.my.package.util;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MyRenderThread extends Thread {

    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private MySurface mSurface;
    private boolean mRunning = false;

    public MyRenderThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, MySurface surface) {
        mSurfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        mSurface = surface;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return mSurfaceHolder;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        mRunning = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        while (mRunning) {
            c = null;
            try {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                    if (c != null) {
                        mSurface.onDraw(c);
                    }
                }
            }
            finally { // when exception is thrown above we may not leave the surface in an inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The `SurfaceView` is included in my `Activity`'s layout XML:

```
<com.my.package.util.MySurface
    android:id="@+id/my_surface"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/my_surface_height" />
```

Then in code it is accessed like this:

```
MySurface mySurface = (MySurface) findViewById(R.id.my_surface);
```

Comment: I've seen that `mSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);` (in the `Activity` using the `SurfaceView`) solves the problem on Android 4.1. How can this be? And even more important, why is that necessary at all, compared to prior Android versions where it was not?

Comment: Post the activity code where you create the surfaceview

Comment: @nathan: Please see above, at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Can you see where the black is coming from? Change canvas.draw color to something else like blue. If you have other layouts or views involved the set a different color on each one. This way we know exactly where black is from.

Comment: The black is just there because nothing is drawn to the canvas. Black = nothingness ;)

Comment: I am having the same problem pls can you tell me how did you solved the problem

Answer (score -1):

Rename your draw method to onDraw2(). Change the thread code to call onDraw2. This way you are not overidding the base class's ondraw. I think you might be getting 2 hits in your onDraw. One from the base class override and one from the thread.

This would explain why setting the z-order helps. You will reverse the order the 2 windows draw therefore avoiding the problem. As to the "why now" part of the question. Since you have the 2 pathways to onDraw I suspect this is unsupported android behavior, so no telling what might happen.

Also I saw you called setDrawingCache enabled. I don't think that is helping you. Usually you would call getDrawingCache at some point. Try removing it if it is not important.

The only other thing I see is that you create the thread and pass the holder in surface created. You might want to take action when surfaceChanged occurs, or at 
Least verify that nothing important has changed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But actually, I don't see how this should solve the problem. Nevertheless, I tried it, of course: Renaming `onDraw()` to `onDraw2()` causes the thread's call to this function to fail, as the base class's `onDraw()` is not visible. No matter if I remove the call to `onDraw()` (thus no drawing) or rename it to call the new `onDraw2()`, the result is the same: The canvas is black when I don't set the Z order.

Comment: I clarified the post. I assume you tried removing setDrawingCacheEnabled as well. Oh well I am out of ideas.